# App Engine flexible restarting from 503 /readiness_check failure

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

My app.yaml configuration has a custom URL `/my_readiness_check` for readiness check instead of the default `/readiness_check`.

I see requests to the custom URL that succeed. Then I see my instance restarted with a SIGKILL to the app and they are immediately preceded by a couple of 503 failures to `/readiness_check`

```
runtime: python
env: flex

readiness_check:
  path: "/my_readiness_check"
  check_interval_sec: 10
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 1
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300

liveness_check:
  path: "/my_liveness_check"
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 30
  failure_threshold: 3
  initial_delay_sec: 60

...
```

Comment: You might want to increase `timeout_sec` or `check_interval_sec` or try to [increase memory allocation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks) by specifying the resources in your `app.yaml`.

Comment: The mystery/bug here is requests to the default /readiness_check when I have configured the readiness check to hit /my_readiness_check. I don't understand why the default URL is even called and only preceding a failure when all other successful 200 requests hit my custom URL